# order of parameter for stat functions

Tags: python, statistics, gamma

I have the following code to estimate the parameters of gamma distribution, generate some reall data with estimated parameters and do kstest:

```
alhpa, beta, loc=gamma.fit(my_data)
real_data=gamma.pdf(my_data, alpha,loc,beta)
stat, pval = kstest (my_data, 'gamma',(alpha,loc))
```

I am not sure about the order of parameters in fir, pdf and kstest. Is there any references for the right order of parameters for each function?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Which library are you using? Did you try looking at their documentation? You could also try running `help(kstest)` in the console to pull up the documentation (if any) for the `kstest` function, for example.

Comment: I am using scipy.stats, there is not document for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the scipy [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) for [gamma](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) and [kstest](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html#scipy.stats.kstest), the order of the arguments are:

```
gamma.fit(data, a, loc=0, scale=1)
gamma.pdf(x, a, loc=0, scale=1)
kstest(rvs, cdf, args=(), N=20, alternative='two-sided', mode='approx')
```

You can find more detailed information about the parameters and usage examples in the documentation linked above.

Comment: This is right, but the order of parameter for kstest does not specified.